# Munin aggregate graphs are not working

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, munin, graph

I know this has been asked in several times on many forums before, but still I am struck with similar problem.

Individual graphs are working fine however, aggregate graphs are not. I don't even get an empty graph (graph without data).

All the machines are running on Ubuntu-12.04 m1.medium ec2 instance. Munin version is 1.4.6.

My munin.conf looks like...

> [localhost.localdomain]
>      address 127.0.0.1
>      use_node_name yes
>
> [.us-west-1.compute.internal]
>       address 
>       use_node_name yes
>
> [.us-west-1.compute.internal]
>       address 
>       use_node_name yes
>
> [.us-west-1.compute.internal]
>       address 
>       use_node_name yes
>
> [us-west-1.compute.internal;totalcheckpoints]
>       update no
>       contacts no
>
> ```
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.update no  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph yes  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph_args --base 1000 -l 0  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.cdef 0  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph_category PG Total Checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph_title Aggregated checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph_vlabel Total Checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.checkpoints_req_total.label Total checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.graph_order checkpoints_req_total  
> postgres_checkpoints_checkpoints_req.checkpoints_req_total.sum \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints_<internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal_checkpoints_req.checkpoints_req \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints_<internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal_checkpoints_req.checkpoints_req \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints_<internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal_checkpoints_req.checkpoints_req
> ```

I have tried following symblinks in /etc/munin/plugins:

> postgres_checkpoints -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/postgres_checkpoints
>   postgres_checkpoints_ -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/postgres_checkpoints
>   postgres_checkpoints__ -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/postgres_checkpoints

As munin user following munin commands are working fine and I don't see anything obviously wrong in the output:

> sudo su - munin -s /bin/bash
>   /usr/share/munin/munin-update --debug --nofork
>   /usr/share/munin/munin-graph --debug --nofork --nolazy
>   /usr/share/munin/munin-html --debug

telnet returns correct info for plugin postgres_checkpoints:

> munin@hostname:~$ telnet  4949
>   Trying ...
>   Connected to .
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>      # munin node at internal-ip-of-munin-node.us-west-1.compute.internal
>   config postgres_checkpoints
>   graph_title PostgreSQL checkpoints
>   graph_vlabel Checkpoints / minute
>   graph_category PostgreSQL
>   graph_info Number of checkpoints per minute
>   graph_args --base 1000
>   graph_period minute   checkpoints_timed.label Timed checkpoints
>   checkpoints_timed.info Checkpoints started by timeout
>   checkpoints_timed.type DERIVE
>   checkpoints_timed.draw LINE1
>   checkpoints_req.label Requested
>   checkpoints
>   checkpoints_req.info
>   Checkpoints started by request
>   checkpoints_req.type DERIVE
>   checkpoints_req.draw STACK
>   .
>   fetch postgres_checkpoints
>   checkpoints_timed.value 2860
>   checkpoints_req.value 37
>   .
>   quit

Logs on munin-master and munin-node do not indicate any obvious errors. Also have verified that everywhere all hostanames are correct fqdn.

Any ideas what am I missing?

I have checked many forums and links. However serverfault is not allowing me to paste more than two links I referred:
 1. http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/aggregate_examples
 2. http://blog.loftninjas.org/2010/04/08/an-evening-with-munin-graph-aggregation/

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it working. Munin is not that bad, all you need is to spend a couple of nights with it.

I misunderstood the documentation, you need not to mention hostname. Plugin name should be exactly same as on munin nodes. Also the same plugin should exist on Munin-master with __.

So, in /etc/munin/plugins now symblinks looks like:

> postgres_checkpoints__ -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/postgres_checkpoints

And here is the new configuration, note the plugin-name after ":" doesn't have hostname in it:

> ```
> postgres_checkpoints_total.update no  
> pg_checkpoints.label Graph label  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph yes  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph_args --base 1000 -l 0  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.cdef 0  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph_category PG Total Checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph_title Aggregated checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph_vlabel Total Checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.checkpoints_req_total.label Total Req checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.checkpoints_timed_total.label Total Timed checkpoints  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.graph_order checkpoints_req_total checkpoints_timed  
> postgres_checkpoints_total.checkpoints_req_total.sum \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-est-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_req \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_req \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_req
>
> postgres_checkpoints_total.checkpoints_timed_total.sum \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_timed \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_timed \  
>         <internal_ip>.us-west-1.compute.internal:postgres_checkpoints.checkpoints_timed
> ```

Also, please note that now in the above configuration I am aggregating 2 functions.